Is it possible to integrate different payment services into my mobile application and website?
I have a mobile application that uses a specific payment service, but I want to integrate a different payment service into my website. Can these services share information?
I was actually trying to look at whether stripe payment service can be integrated into Drupal, but I couldn't find a reliable module, so I want to investigate other services.

I think you need to add a bit more context to your ask and add more details/code if you can. I see this Drupal project, https://www.drupal.org/project/stripe_api which might be a good start.

The problem is that the modules I'm finding don't seem to have much activity.
